# Restoring boot manager for secondary harddrive with windows 7 installed

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

A while back I took the hard drive out of my laptop and put it on my computer. I never got round to removing the windows install but removed the partition.

I now need access to windows 7 so I thought I could just boot from the hard drive but it is not recognized as bootable.

How could I go about configuring the hard drive so I could boot windows 7 from it? The main harddrive runs windows 10.

Comment: why not rebuild it with Windows 7?